# Rails Permitting Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, typically I would only permit certain parameters when a form is submitted by declaring a private function with the following code:

```
params.require(:object).permit(:name, :email, :phone)
```

However, I'm using form_tag instead of form_for and therefore each field is submitted in the params hash. As I'm not a ruby/rails expert, what's the best way to permit these parameters in an efficient way?

Is this right?

```
params.require(:params).permit(:name, :email, :phone)
```

Comment: i think you could answer your own question here.  Did it work when you tried to use that?  If so, then it is right! `:)`

Comment: you can safely remove the `require(:params)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the correct solution:

```
params.permit(:name, :email, :phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the `params.permit` line like Lichtamberg suggested, however depending on your implementation, you might break other other routes (especially the RESTful ones). If this is the only page that behaves like this (with the `form_tag`), one thing you can do is alter the form inputs to match the structure of a regular `form_for` form by passing in the name of the variable, like so:

```
<%= label_tag :object, :name %>
<%= text_field_tag :object, :name %>
```

This then results in a parameter map that looks like:

```
{
    :object => {
        :name => "tommyd456",
        :email => "bla@bla.com"
        ...etc ...etc
```

Which is then perfectly valid for the original `params.require(:object)` line.

Check out [this link from the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects) for more info.

Comment: @tommyd456 No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer, if any answered your question adequately.

Comment: Yes my question was answered by delba but it was in the comments section so I couldn't mark it as answered - but I did mark it as useful. If he had put his response as an answer I would have "ticked" it too. And that's why i haven't ticked your response even though it was very useful.

Comment: @tommyd456 Fair enough. You can always post your own answer and accept if you want as well.